# SQL Server best approch to append table data into Oracle database table

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a table for bio-metric devices which capture the data as soon as the employees punch their fingers and uses SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition.

However, our legacy devices were exporting log files and we used a vb engine to push to our Oracle table and used to generate the attendance details.

I managed to export the data from SQL Server and built the first set of records. I would like to schedule a JOB with SQL Server with a condition that the Oracle table should receive ONLY the rows those are NOT already inserted from the SQL Server table.

I checked the append possibilities, which dumps the entire SQL Server table data when the job is executed thus duplicating the rows within the Oracle target table, forcing me to discard the job and to build a new one that deletes the Oracle table and recreates when the job is executed. I feel this is a kind of overkill...

Any known methods available to append only the rows those are NOT existing in the Oracle target table? Unfortunately the SQL Server tables doesn't have any unique id column for the transaction.

Please suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't have a unique ID then how are you deciding that the data already exists? Are there multiple columns that together form a unique key for your purposes? And, look into the merge statement...

Comment: Hello Alex, this is what the exact problem I'm also concerned about. Unfortunately the database is set by the device software, which we cannot modify. It looks like I have to stick to the job I created deleting the table and recreating it regularly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use sal server replication with Oracle database as subscriber.
You can read about this solution on MSDN site:
[Oracle Subscribers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151738.aspx)

Regards
Giova

Comment: Hello Giova, I have gone through the link and looks like Subscriber should be the best option in our case. Thank you very much. I will try to setup an environment and get back to this thread with results

Comment: @raj Hi Raj, the configuration is not hard to complete. let  me know.

Comment: Hello @Giova, Microsoft states this feature would be discarded with the future builds of SQL server & once after evaluating the efforts, We have decided to schedule a job to drop and recreate the SQL table in Oracle database. Thanks buddy, I never knew about the subscriber property and glad that you pointed me towards something new and exciting.

Comment: though the topic is few weeks old, finally I came to a solution for my concerns! It is "linked" servers & after combining three columns from the solution provider's table I was able to do a quick if exist and to append the missing records in Oracle table. Hope this helps someone else out there [link](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/connecting-sql-server-and-oracle-using-linked-servers) [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic482481-146-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about attendance data for something like an electronic time card, you could just send the data where the punch time is > the last time stamp synced.  You would need to maintain that value some where, and it doesn't take into account retro actively entered records.  If there's a record creation date in addition to the punch time you could use the created date.  Further if there is a modified date in the record you could look into using the merge statement as Alex Pool suggested so you could get both new records and modifications synced to oracle.